# Calculating the dimension of a finite intersection of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have trouble with the follwoing task:

---

Let $A,B \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ be two matrices. Consider the kernel $W=ker(B-A)$ with $dim(W)=n-1$. Consider $V= W \cap A^{-1}W \cap ... \cap A^{-(n-2)}W$ and show that  $dim(V) \geq 1$.

---

My first idea, was to use the formula
$$dim(U\cap T)=dim(U)+dim(T)−dim(U+T)$$
by setting $U:=W$ and $T:= A^{-1}W \cap ... \cap A^{-(n-2)}W$ and using $dim(U)=n-1$.
We note, that the dimension of $U \cap T$ can be no more than the dimension of $U$ nor more the dimension of $T$. But how do i find the missing dimensions?

Comment: Surely the exponent of $A^{n - 2}$ must be negative? Or $A^{-1}W$ should be $AW$?

Comment: @AnneBauval It would help, if the $A^{-j}W$ were hyperplanes.

Comment: They are since $W$ is and $A\in GL_n.$

Comment: @TheoBendit You are right, it has to be $V=\cap_{j=0}^{n-2}A^{-j}W$.